# Can I use JavaScript to get the dimensions that media queries use?

Tags: javascript, css

For example here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gup43rx/2/) which shows how to change a font when the width drops below 200px.

```
@media (max-width: 200px) {
  .test {
    font-size:40px;
  }
}
```

If you move the html window to the right to make it smaller you will see the point at which it hits 200px b.c. the font will change.

If someone could add a dynamic div to the fiddle so that this value would be output to the window this would be a cool test script for media queries.

Also, if there is a good reference on the web for the JavaScript interface to media queries.  I hope there is one.  I have not found it yet.

Comment: Here's a reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Comment: Thx, but my question must not be clear.  I wanted a property that gives the width that media queries use.  I can determine it from this but I would have to set up multiple event handlers for each point I wanted to check for ....10px, 20px, 20px, .... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you were actually asking for.  The snippet below will output the dimensions that media query uses.

http://jsfiddle.net/jbnt7nh1/8/

```
// some code - updated fiddle
```

Here is a good point to start reading about the different widths in CSS.

https://www.google.com/#q=quirksmode+screen+width

Answer (score 2):

You can add an event listener to `window.matchMedia`

```
if (matchMedia) {
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 200px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {

    if (mq.matches) {
        console.log('matches')
    }

}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jbnt7nh1/)**

Comment: Worth adding that if (matchMedia) fails in IE9 and below. 
http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia

Comment: @DasBeasto ah, that's interesting, I assumed I could use it wherever I could use media queries themselves. I guess that Leaves IE9 hanging. Yet another reason why I hate IE

Comment: I've seen this before, I was looking for an update as you change the window, a continuous stream, my guess is you would have to determine a precision, say 10px and then set up a multitude of event listeners for each point.

Comment: ok, I dont think there is a defined way of reading the media queries using javascript. [this guy](http://zerosixthree.se/detecting-media-queries-with-javascript/) came up with a pretty good hack using the `:after` pseudo selector

Answer (score 1):

I did using jQuery, hope this helps.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
if($(window).width()<=200){
    $(".test").css("font-size","40px");
}
else{
    $(".test").css("font-size","20px");
} });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7gup43rx/2/

Comment: Nice, but nobody seems to know which JS dimension media queries actually uses, and there are quite a few.